# Left Outer Join, No result in final query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join, full-outer-join

I'm executing the following query

```
Select * from A a left outer join B b on (b.id = a.id)
```

I'm getting one record from A and no records from B. I'm expecting one record in final select query but getting none.

Here is some sample data:

A

```
v_id, id,      date,      d_id
1,    1244578, 02-MAR-11, 1827877
```

B, no data presented:

```
e_id,id,amount
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it do like this ?

Comment: Show some records please

Comment: records are like this
A(v_id,id,date,d_id) (1,1244578,02-MAR-11,1827877)     AND 
B(e_id,id,amount)[no data present]

Comment: @KrantiKumarMishra - We are not talking about output data. We are talking about input data.

Comment: Or you are running a different query or on different tables or in tables are not the things you are thinking on.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
Select *
from A a 
left outer join B b on b."id" = a."id"
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85cff/3)

This will give you:

```
| V_ID |      ID |      DATE |    D_ID |   E_ID | AMOUNT |
----------------------------------------------------------
|    1 | 1244578 | 02-MAR-11 | 1827877 | (null) | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting one record from Table A this is because table A has only one record and Table B have no record.
In left outer join content of first table is show in result join with second table but in your case second table have no records so final result show null values for that records.